# Julia CUDA - Reduce matrix columns

Tags: cuda, julia, gpu

Consider the following kernel, which reduces along the *rows* of a 2-D matrix

```
function row_sum!(x, ncol, out)
    """out = sum(x, dims=2)"""
    row_idx = (blockIdx().x-1) * blockDim().x + threadIdx().x
    for i = 1:ncol
        @inbounds out[row_idx] += x[row_idx, i]
    end
    return
end

N = 1024
x = CUDA.rand(Float64, N, 2*N)
out = CUDA.zeros(Float64, N)
@cuda threads=256 blocks=4 row_sum!(x, size(x)[2], out)
isapprox(out, sum(x, dims=2))  # true
```

How do I write a similar kernel except for reducing along the *columns* (of a 2-D matrix)? In particular, how do I get the index of each column, similar to how we got the index of each row with `row_idx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
function col_sum!(x, nrow, out)
    """out = sum(x, dims=1)"""
    col_idx = (blockIdx().x-1) * blockDim().x + threadIdx().x
    for i = 1:nrow
        @inbounds out[col_idx] += x[i, col_idx]
    end
    return
end

N = 1024
x = CUDA.rand(Float64, N, 2N)
out = CUDA.zeros(Float64, 2N)
@cuda threads=256 blocks=8 col_sum!(x, size(x, 1), out)
```

And here is the test:

```
julia> isapprox(out, vec(sum(x, dims=1)))
true
```

As you can see the size of the result vector is now `2N` instead of `N`, hence we had to adapt the number of `blocks` accordingly (that is multiply by `2` and now we have `8` instead of `4`)

More materials can be found here: https://juliagpu.gitlab.io/CUDA.jl/tutorials/introduction/

Comment: Awesome answer. I didn't realize that the thread indexing code could be the exact same, and changing just the block size gets us the desired behavior. Thanks!

Comment: You have  `blockIdx().y` and `blockIdx().z` but these are for multi-dimensional blocks. Here the block remains one-dimensional so almost no change in the code.